# jQuery plugin, make methods available for all the objects

Tags: jquery

i´m having some troubles with the scope in a jquery plugin.
I have the following:

```
$.fn.plugin(){
   all the code inside here
}
```

But my code is starting to be a little heavy so i´m trying to reorganize in differents functions:

```
$.fn.plugin(){
   function one(){}
   function two(){}
   ...
}
```

But doing this these functions are defined for each objet passed to the plugin.
So i´m wondering if is there a better way to do it, make the declaration of these functions common to all the objects but at the same time i want to keep the reference to the objetct that is calling the method.
Something like this.

```
$.fn.plugin(){}
function one(){I need to access "this" inside}
function two(){I need to access "this" inside}
   ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: yeah, like your last snippet, only wrapped in an IIFE. you can then *call* them with whatever context you want.

Comment: And how can i access to the "this" that is calling the function. Sending it as a parameter?

Comment: you... *call* it. with `call`

Comment: And what if i need to modify the DOM in that "this" that is calling the function. Is still better to declare the functions otuside the plugin?

Comment: ... you would use `this` of course.

Comment: eh, i don't believe in *"better"*. it's subjective, and meaningless in dev. Do what's more maintainable/readable instead.

Comment: xD I´ll try to do it. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @KevinB could you write your comment as a clear & complete _answer_. That shows what relevant context might want to be passed, and how to pass the relevant context?